# Extracting multiple rows from a table with two linked tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, let's call it `Case` the case table contains basic information about a case, such as the `CaseNumber` and the `CaseOwner`.

In a second table `CasePersons`, details about individuals attached to a particular case number are held. This includes `PersonId`, `FirstName` and `LastName`. `CasePersons` links to `Case` through `CaseNumber`.

In a third table, `ContactDetails` a number of phone numbers associated with a particular person are stored. The `Type` column within `ContactDetails` represents the type of phone number e.g. Home, mobile or work. `ContactDetails` links to `CasePersons` through `PersonId`

More clearly:

```
Case
------------------------
CaseNumber     CaseOwner
1              Owner1
2              Owner2
3              Owner3

CasePersons
---------------------
PersonId        CaseNumber      FirstName     LastName
1               1               Bob           Person
2               1               Jim           Human
3               2               Gary          Man
4               3               Pete          Smith
5               3               Matt          Jones


CaseDetails
-------------------------
PersonId       Detail        Type
1              0123456789    1
1              1111111111    2
2              2222222222    1
1              0101001011    3
2              1234123412    2
3              0000011111    1
3              1231231231    2
```

I want to be able to write a query that can pull back the basic details of a case, as well as all of the individuals associated with a case and ALL of the associated phone numbers.

How exactly would I construct a query to extract this information? I can't seem to find the information on this on Google as I'm not sure what to search for.

The whole point of this is so that I can find all of the associated numbers for a particular case and store them in one location.

Expected output

```
CaseNumber    CaseOwner    Person1FirstName     Person1LastName     Person1HomeNumber    Person1MobileNumber     Person1WorkNumber     Person2FirstName     Person2LastName     Person2HomeNumber    Person2MobileNumber     Person2WorkNumber  
1             Owner1       Bob                  Person              0123456789           1111111111              0101001011            Jim                  Human               2222222222           1234123412
```

Comment: add your expected output in table format

Comment: @fa06 Added the expected output to the OP

Comment: As far as having dedicated columns for `person1`, `person2`, etc.  You don't.  That's an extremely non-sql way of looking at things.  By all means transpose the data when presenting it in a GUI or something, but you do that application side, not database side.  In terms of data processing, in terms of SQL and relational databases, stick to the normalised structure *(one person per row, so you can have as many people as you like without having to change the structure or the query)*.

Comment: @MatBailie What should I do if the database I'm extracting this data from has two people associated with a particular case in a single row? There will only ever be a maximum of two people associated with a case, but the details of these two people are stored within the same row. Should I separate the data within SQL or do this later on out of the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with all the information for one case showing up in multiple rows, you can use multiple joins and an order by to place related rows together.

```
select
    Case.CaseNumber
    ,CaseOwner
    ,CasePersons.PersonID
    ,FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,Detail
    ,Type
from
    Case
    join CasePersons
    on Case.CaseNumber=CasePersons.Casenumber
    join CaseDetails
    on CasePersons.PersonID=CaseDetails.PersonID
Order by
    Case.CaseNumber
    ,CasePersons.PersonID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just joining on the respective columns of the tables would do.

Eg: 
Step 1:You get all of the case information from "Case" table so this would be your driving table.
Step 2: To get all the persons involved in your case, join with the "CasePersons" table
       case.CaseNumber=casepersons.CaseNumber
Step 3: Now you got all persons associated with a case as the result of step 2. After this you are interested in extracting the phone numbers of the persons who are involved in your case,so join 
      casepersons.personid=casedetails.personid

Query

```
 select case.CaseNumber
           ,case.CaseOwner
           ,casepersons.personid
           ,casepersons.firstname
           ,casepersons.lastname
           ,casedetails.Detail
           ,casedetails.Type
           ,case when casedetails.Type=1 then 'Home'
                 when casedetails.Type=2 then 'Mobile'
                 when casedetails.Type=3 then 'Work'
            end as phone_type 
      from case 
      join casepersons
        on case.CaseNumber=casepersons.CaseNumber
      join (select personid
                   ,max(case when casedetails.Type=1 then details end) as Home_number
                   ,max(case when casedetails.Type=2 then details end) as Work_number
                   ,max(case when casedetails.Type=3 then details end) as Mobile_number
              from casedetails
          group by personid) as cd_1
        on casepersons.personid=cd_1.personid
```

Comment: So this is close to what I want, except I'd like the Home, Mobile and Work values held in detail to go into three separate columns depending on the value of type. So if `type == 1` then the `Home Number` field is populated, `type == 2` then the `Mobile Number` field is populated etc, how do I do this?

Comment: I have tried using three separate cases to populate the fields, but this seems to produce three rows and only populates one of the three fields, not all three.

Comment: Modified the query to show up the phone numbers aggregated by personid

Answer (score 0):

you can check the following script. I have added dynamic table which is related with maximum person added to the CasePersons table for each case.

```
/*
DROP TABLE #Case;
DROP TABLE #CasePersons;
DROP TABLE #CaseDetails;
DROP TABLE #CaseTemp;
*/
CREATE TABLE #Case
(
    CaseNumber  INT
    ,CaseOwner  VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #Case VALUES(1,'Owner1'),(2,'Owner2'),(3,'Owner3');

CREATE TABLE #CasePersons
(
    PersonId    INT
    ,CaseNumber INT
    ,FirstName  VARCHAR(100)
    ,LastName   VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #CasePersons
VALUES(1,1,'Bob','Person'),(2,1,'Jim','Human'),(3,2,'Gary','Man'),(4,3,'Pete','Smith'),(5,3,'Matt','Jones');

CREATE TABLE #CaseDetails
(
    PersonId    INT
    ,Detail     VARCHAR(100)
    ,[TYPE]     INT
);

INSERT INTO #CaseDetails
VALUES
(1,'0123456789',1)
,(1,'1111111111',2)
,(2,'2222222222',1)
,(1,'0101001011',3)
,(2,'1234123412',2)
,(3,'0000011111',1)
,(3,'1231231231',2);



    SELECT c.CaseNumber
            ,c.CaseOwner
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.CaseNumber ORDER BY CD.PersonId) RowNumber
            ,CP.PersonId
            ,CP.FirstName
            ,CP.LastName
            ,CD.HomeNumber
            ,CD.MobileNumber
            ,CD.WorkNumber
    INTO #CaseTemp
    FROM #Case C
    LEFT JOIN #CasePersons CP ON C.CaseNumber = CP.CaseNumber
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT PersonId
                ,MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE=1 THEN Detail END) HomeNumber 
                ,MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE=2 THEN Detail END) MobileNumber 
                ,MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE=3 THEN Detail END) WorkNumber 
        FROM #CaseDetails
        GROUP BY PersonId
    ) CD ON CP.PersonId = CD.PersonId
    --WHERE CD.TYPE=1
    ORDER BY C.CaseNumber
             ,CP.PersonId

--Create result table            
DROP TABLE #CaseList
GO
CREATE TABLE #CaseList
(
    CaseNumber  INT
    ,CaseOwner  VARCHAR(100)
    ,Person1FirstName   VARCHAR(100)
    ,Person1LastName    VARCHAR(100)
    ,Person1HomeNumber  VARCHAR(100)
    ,Person1MobileNumber VARCHAR(100)
    ,Person1WorkNumber  VARCHAR(100)
)

--Insert first person details to the table
INSERT INTO #CaseList
SELECT   CaseNumber
        ,CaseOwner
        ,FirstName
        ,LastName
        ,HomeNumber
        ,MobileNumber
        ,WorkNumber
FROM #CaseTemp
WHERE RowNumber=1

--Create additional person fields
    DECLARE @SQLString  VARCHAR(MAX)=''
    DECLARE @MaxPerson  INT=(SELECT MAX(RowNumber) FROM #CaseTemp)
    DECLARE @Seq    int=2

    --
    WHILE @MaxPerson>=@Seq
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLString='ALTER TABLE #CaseList ADD Person'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+'FirstName VARCHAR(100);'
        SET @SQLString=@SQLString+CHAR(13)+'ALTER TABLE #CaseList ADD Person'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+'LastName  VARCHAR(100);'
        SET @SQLString=@SQLString+CHAR(13)+'ALTER TABLE #CaseList ADD Person'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+'HomeNumber  VARCHAR(100);'
        SET @SQLString=@SQLString+CHAR(13)+'ALTER TABLE #CaseList ADD Person'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+'MobileNumber  VARCHAR(100);'
        SET @SQLString=@SQLString+CHAR(13)+'ALTER TABLE #CaseList ADD Person'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+'WorkNumber  VARCHAR(100);'
        SET @Seq +=1
    END

    EXEC (@SQLString)

--Update additional person details 
SET @SQLString=''

SET @Seq=2
WHILE @MaxPerson>=@Seq
BEGIN
    SET @SQLString=@SQLString+CHAR(13)+'UPDATE #CaseList SET Person'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+'FirstName   =CT.FirstName 
                                                            ,Person'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+'LastName    =CT.LastName
                                                            ,Person'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+'HomeNumber  =CT.HomeNumber
                                                            ,Person'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+'MobileNumber=CT.MobileNumber
                                                            ,Person'+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+'WorkNumber  =CT.WorkNumber                                                      
                                        FROM #CaseTemp CT 
                                        WHERE #CaseList.CaseNumber=CT.CaseNumber AND CT.RowNumber='+CAST(@Seq AS VARCHAR)+''
    SET @Seq +=1
END

EXEC (@SQLString)

--SELECT * FROM #CaseTemp
SELECT * FROM #CaseList
```